# running the first Qt + ffmpeg profram: undefined reference av_register_all

Tags: qt, ffmpeg, qt-creator

I am trying to include ffmpeg in my qt project on windows (I use QT Creator).
I wrote a small program.

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    av_register_all();

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the problem

```
undefined reference av_register_all
```

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: You're trying to use libavcodec without linking with it.

Comment: Add these lines in your ".pro" file INCLUDEPATH += C:/Users/XX/ffmpeg-2.1.3-mingw32pcx+msvc/include
LIBS += -LC:/Users/XX/ffmpeg-2.1.3-mingw32pcx+msvc/lib
LIBS += -lavcodec -lavfilter -lavformat -lavutil -lswscale  -lswresample